# MySQL Error - unused primary key value returns already used

Tags: mysql

MySQL MyISAM database which currently has 2,280 rows in a table has locked up twice in the past 6 months or so.

When trying to add a new row it says "Primary key already used", when the next increment value is higher than the last id in the table. Seems to fix itself when I reset the auto increment.

Database is for a site which gets around 200+ hits a day, peak of about 25-20 an hour, so can't imagine it's due to overload on the database.

Trying to figure out why this keeps happening and if I can fix the issue so the client doesn't have to keep calling up whenever they can't add a new article to their site.

EDIT: Just to preempt potential comments, I realise that the table and code are not ideal, but I'm not looking for ways I should improve this, unless it's the root cause of the problem, poor performance/security I can live with (just), but I do need to figure out what could be causing it to lock the table. Thanks.

Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `article_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_meta_desc` text,
  `article_meta_keyw` text,
  `article_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_date` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_intro` text,
  `article_embed` text,
  `article_content` text,
  `article_sector` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_ma` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_pn` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_cw` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_er` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_kr` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_rc` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_rs` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_img_s` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_img_l` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_highlight` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_slug` text,
  `article_alias` text,
  `article_hide` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `article_ad_layout` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `article_ad_banner` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_ad_sky` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_ad_square1` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_ad_square2` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_ad_square3` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_newswire` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `full_text` (`article_title`,`article_intro`,`article_content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2384 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

_ma,_pn,_cw,_er,_kr,_rc,_rs are used for showing which category articles are for. Please ignore the bad use of a table for the ads and section, site was made quite a long time ago, I have learnt better since :p

Insert statement

```
INSERT INTO articles (article_id, article_meta_desc, article_meta_keyw, article_title, article_date, article_intro, article_embed, article_content, article_sector, article_type, article_ma, article_pn, article_cw, article_er, article_kr, article_rc, article_rs, article_img_s, article_img_l, article_link, article_highlight, article_slug, article_alias, article_hide)
VALUES ('','$insert_article_meta_desc','$insert_article_meta_keyw','$insert_article_title','$insert_article_date','$insert_article_intro','$insert_article_embed','$insert_article_content','$insert_article_sector','$insert_article_category','$insert_article_ma','$insert_article_pn','$insert_article_cw','$insert_article_er','$insert_article_kr','$insert_article_rc','$insert_article_rs','$insert_article_img_s','$insert_article_img_l','','$insert_article_highlight','$insert_article_slug','','$insert_article_hide')
```

Again, old site, please forgive me. Not sure if it's something to do with doing an insert that sets the id to '' which would then be set to the next increment value, could this cause problems?

Comment: What is the definition of the table, and what is the auto increment when you need to reset it?

Comment: forgive my ignorance, definition? inc value was 1 above the last id in the table, so there shouldn't have been a conflict.

Comment: Can you post the table definition? And maybe the insert statements that is causing the lock up? It would help a lot.

Comment: Just so. The definition can be obtained with the `DESCRIBE tablename` command, and is something like: `CREATE TABLE tablename ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(30), ...`.

Comment: "inc value was 1 above the last id in the table"... so what was the id, and what value did you reset the autoincrement to?

Comment: (This starts looking like a *programming* error, not a MySQL issue. Is the original error anything like `ERROR 1062 (23000)`?)

Comment: Can you post the **EXACT** error message you are getting?

Comment: ah right, for some reason the word order confused me. 'definition of table' confused me, 'table definition' made sense.

Comment: @Jocelyn - unfortunately not. I was too busy trying to fix the problem to note it down for later, my bad, and it's hard to replicate the issue other than keep adding stuff to see if it breaks again.

Comment: @Iserni - the same eg. value was 1234, last row in table was 1233, yet adding a new row would say 'already in use'. On auto_inc reset value was still 1234 but table would then allow me to add a new row.

Comment: May I inquire why you use the article_id field in the insert statement, when you have defined it as an auto increment integer, and furthermore, why you pass an empty string into it?

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE - I was young, I didn't know any better. At the time, I thought it was needed, which I know now isn't the case. If this could legitimately be the cause of the problem, could you give me details as to why?

Comment: Well, I've just tried the same with a database on my end. I get an error message, which would be expected, as an empty string cannot be inserted into an integer field. Having said that, it seems that your application has no problem with it, or none that you see. I'd say it's possible that this is the cause of your error, but i'd wager that what happens when you do this is highly unspecified. I'd suggest you take the empty string and article_id field from your insert statement and try running without them and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE - Yeah, was thinking that'd probably be the best when I looked at the insert query again, stupid old sites. Would be really helpful to get some concrete proof that this is causing a problem, or something entirely different, as it could be another 6 months before it happens again under normal use and I don't really have time to run tests.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you create a new database on the same server (to use the same version number of MySQL), create a new naked database with just an id and data field and try to insert an empty string into an id via MySQL Admin or command line. Check which error message fires, or if it's only a warning or imperfect conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the article_id field name, and first '' in the values, from the INSERT stmt; the auto increment ID should get allocated automatically.

Comment: is this likely to cause issues is specific situations, like two articles being added at the same time, or is this more just good practise. As I mentioned, this is old code, so wouldn't normally do it like that anymore, but not sure how likely it is to cause issues.

Comment: it's designed to do the opposite, protect you from such things